# How to reset LazyColumn scrollState to a specific itemsIndexed() item?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a `LazyColumn` with an `item {}`, a `stickyHeader {}` and, depending on the Tab selected in the content of the stickyHeader, a list of either product items or picklist items.

Now, I have noticed that if the user taps on any of the tabs, scrolls a bit in the `itemsIndexed {}` list and then switches the active tab and thus the active list of items, the scroll offset is preserved between the lists. For example, scrolling to product number 4 and then tapping on the picklists tab, will display the list in a scrolled state starting from picklist number 4.

I want to avoid this, but I am not sure how to go about it. I have tried using `scrollTo()` and `animateScrollToItem()` but don't know how to use these (if possible), to scroll to the first item in the currently active itemsIndexed list upon tab selection?

Here is my composable:

```
@OptIn(
    ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class
)
@Composable
fun BatchDetailsScreen(
    batchDetailsViewModel: BatchDetailsViewModel = koinInject(),
    batchUUID: String,
    batchRefId: String,
) {
    val navViewModel = LocalNavViewModel.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    var shouldShowScanContainerBottomSheet by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var shouldShowPickProductsInPicklistBottomSheet by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    var picklistToPickFrom: BatchPicklistDetails? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }
    val scanProductSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true
    )
    var productToPick: P2CProduct? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }
    val batchDetailsUiState by batchDetailsViewModel.batchDetailsUiStateFlow.collectAsState(
        BatchDetailsUiState(isLoading = true)
    )
    val picklistsCompleted by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            batchDetailsUiState.batchDetailsResponse?.batchDetails?.picklistsInfo?.picklists?.count {
                it.getPicklistStatus() == PicklistStatus.COMPLETED
            }
                ?: 0
        }
    }
    val totalProductsInBatch by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            batchDetailsUiState.productsAndPicksResponse?.products?.size ?: 0
        }
    }
    val batchWorkflow by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            batchDetailsUiState.batchDetailsResponse?.batchDetails?.getWorkflowType()
                ?: BatchWorkflow.NOT_AVAILABLE
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        navViewModel.setAppBarState(
            AppBarState(
                "Batch - $batchRefId",
            )
        )
        batchDetailsViewModel.fetchBatchDetails(batchUUID) {
            Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    val dominantColor = LocalDominantColor.current
    var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    if (batchDetailsUiState.isLoading) {
        Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = dominantColor
            )
        }
    } else if (batchDetailsUiState.isError) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(48.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.failed_to_load_content_error_msg))
        }
    } else {
        val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
        LazyColumn(
            state = scrollState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(0xfff5f5f5))
                .padding(16.dp),
        ) {
            item {
                Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
                BatchInfoHeader(batchDetailsUiState, totalProductsInBatch, picklistsCompleted)
                Spacer(Modifier.height(8.dp))
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    //todo:sp pass picklist and product from scan
                    BottomSheetDebugOptions(
                        { shouldShowScanContainerBottomSheet = it },
                        onPicklistToPickFromSelected = { picklistToPickFrom = it },
                        batchDetailsUiState,
                        onProductToPickSelected = {
                            productToPick = it
                        }
                    ) { shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet = it }
                }
                Spacer(Modifier.height(16.dp))
            }
            stickyHeader {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .wrapContentHeight(),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 6.dp,
                        topEnd = 6.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp
                    ),
                    elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(defaultElevation = 4.dp),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = Color.White,
                        contentColor = Color.Black
                    )
                ) {
                    PicklistsAndProductsTabRow(
                        Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(),
                        selectedTabIndex,
                        onTabSelected = {
                            selectedTabIndex = it
                            // if user has scrolled enough to activate the sticky header,
                            // tab clicks should reset the scroll position to avoid preserving
                            // the scroll state of one tab list across other tab content
//                            coroutineScope.launch {
//                                scrollState.animateScrollToItem(1, 0)
//                            }
                        },
                        batchWorkflow
                    )
                }
            }
            if (selectedTabIndex == 0 && batchWorkflow == BatchWorkflow.PICKLIST_TO_CONTAINER
                || selectedTabIndex == 1 && batchWorkflow == BatchWorkflow.PRODUCT_TO_CONTAINER
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(
                    List(15) {
                        batchDetailsUiState.batchDetailsResponse?.batchDetails?.picklistsInfo?.picklists
                            ?: emptyList()
                    }.flatten(),
                    key = { _, _ -> UUID.randomUUID() }) { index, picklist ->
                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight(),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 0.dp,
                            topEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = if (index == 14) 6.dp else 0.dp,
                            bottomEnd = if (index == 14) 6.dp else 0.dp
                        ),
                        elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(defaultElevation = 4.dp),
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = Color.White,
                            contentColor = Color.Black
                        )
                    ) {
                        PicklistListItem(index, picklist)
                    }
                }
            } else if (selectedTabIndex == 0 && batchWorkflow == BatchWorkflow.PRODUCT_TO_CONTAINER
                || selectedTabIndex == 1 && batchWorkflow == BatchWorkflow.PICKLIST_TO_CONTAINER
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(
                    List(15) {
                        batchDetailsUiState.productsAndPicksResponse?.products
                            ?: emptyList()
                    }.flatten(),
                    key = { _, _ -> UUID.randomUUID() }) { index, product ->
                    Card(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentHeight(),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 0.dp,
                            topEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = if (index == 14) 6.dp else 0.dp,
                            bottomEnd = if (index == 14) 6.dp else 0.dp
                        ),
                        elevation = CardDefaults.elevatedCardElevation(defaultElevation = 4.dp),
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = Color.White,
                            contentColor = Color.Black
                        )
                    ) {
                        ProductListItem(index, product, context)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (shouldShowScanContainerBottomSheet && picklistToPickFrom != null) {
        ScanContainerModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = { shouldShowScanContainerBottomSheet = false },
            picklistReference = picklistToPickFrom?.reference!!,
            onManualContainerCodeSubmission = {
                //todo:sp call the assign container :)
                //todo:sp add actual business logic
                Toast.makeText(context, "Test submission of $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        )
    }
    if (shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet && picklistToPickFrom != null && productToPick != null) {
        PickProductModalBottomSheet(
            sheetState = scanProductSheetState,
            onDismissRequest = { shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet = false },
            selectedPicklistDetails = picklistToPickFrom!!,
            selectedProduct = productToPick!!
        ) {
            coroutineScope
                .launch {
                    scanProductSheetState.hide()
                }.invokeOnCompletion {
                    shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet = false
                    shouldShowPickProductsInPicklistBottomSheet = true
                }
        }
    }
    if (shouldShowPickProductsInPicklistBottomSheet) {
        shouldShowPickProductBottomSheet = false
        picklistToPickFrom?.let {
            PickProductsInPicklistBottomSheet(
                picklistDetails = it,
                onProductScanned = { uuid ->
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Scanned $uuid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }) {
                shouldShowPickProductsInPicklistBottomSheet = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```